# Django REST Framework Partial update and validation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to perform a partial update on my serializer. The problem is that I have a some validation at object level. So the `is_valid()` call always fails and I can't save the the updated serializer.
Can I somehow prevent the object level validation on partial updates?
Here a code sample:

```
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('field_b','field_b')

    def validate(self,attrs):
         if attrs.get('field_a') <= attrs.get('field_b'):
             raise serializers.ValidationError('Error')
```

And in my viewset the partial update method:

```
class ModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.serialize(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    new_instance = serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem ist that I cannot update 'field_a' without 'field_b'.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please mention what do you mean by object level validation? Please post some code to understand clearly.

Comment: The documentation mentions two types of validation, "field-level" and "object-level". http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

For the "object-level" validation I need a full object with all fields. So I think it shoudn't be called for partial updates. But is_valid() always fails because of the object level validation

Comment: I believe django rest framework has a formal solution to this now. Please check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates.

Answer (score 13):

`self.instance` is how to access the instance in the validator.  Here's an example:

```
def validate_my_field(self, value):
    """ Can't modify field's value after initial save """
    if self.instance and self.instance.my_field != value:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("changing my_field not allowed")
    return value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "partial" argument in order to allow partial updates:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates